# Wordpress - Static php application pulling footer from theme

Tags: wordpress

Okay, I've been punching myself in the face over this for days...

I did not build this website, I just maintain it now...

This wordpress site has a custom built php application in the folder wccm. So if you go to www.test.com/wccm it pulls up the index page with no problem just like it was a normal non-wordpress site(Please note: this is not using a template, or any htaccess inside the folder). Now when I copy the folder and rename it to anything, say wccm2, and go to www.test.com/wccm2 the page loads the bottom **half** of the footer from my main wordpress theme!

Its crazy because, at the top it will echo half of our last link html code like this:

est.com/contact-us/">Contact Us

then under that, the copy right info at the bottom, just like in my themes footer.

I have no idea why this is happening but I know it has nothing to do with the index.php file in the wccm folder because no matter what php file I put in there or what it's name is, it always shows the same thing from my themes footer.

Here is my sites main htaccess file, but it dosen't look like there is anything controlling this folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: you must take a look at the code, or paste some code here

Comment: code from what? no matter what code is in index.php, it shows the bottom half of my main themes footer, and if I keep refreshing it will keep showing only the bottom half of the themes footer but chopped off at a slightly different place every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, I've figured it out.

anytime I would FTP files onto my server, it would make the owner/group "root"

After I used WinSCP to change my users to match each website, it worked perfectly.

cPanel is a pain.